# Google Play internal testing link not working?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have uploaded a version of an app for internal testing in the Google Play Store. The app was in production mode, however, we had to unpublish it for requesting a takedown that never happened in the end, so right now, the app remains in an "Unpublished" status.

When I uploaded the version for internal testing and shared the link among the testers, when they try to access the Play Store, the testers get an error page every single time, so they cannot download the app to their phones.

So, my question is, should I change the app to a "Published" or "Draft" state in order for the internal testing page to work? Or what can I do as a workaround?